# Mask a HTML5 video

Tags: html, css

I would like to mask a HTML5 video element and convert it into a triangle. I want a solution that will work in IE9, Firefox and Chrome. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask videos using SVG in Firefox, but that won't work for IE9 or chrome. You could copy the video frame by frame to a canvas element and then manipulate the video there to create a Mask effect. Using just CSS though it is not possible as far as I am aware.

Comment: How do you copy a video frame by frame?

Comment: I did something similar on my blog last year: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thebeebs/archive/2010/11/08/how-to-rotate-html5-video.aspx

Comment: Thanks, also found a good article here https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Manipulating_video_using_canvas ideally though I would like to do this without using canvas.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how cross-browser compatible this is but I know that Apple has a [Safari Technology Demo](http://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/video-effects.php) where they use `-webkit-mask` on an HTML5 video. It might be worth investigating.

Comment: Since it's a Safari Demo, it will work on webkit-based engines (as, for instance, Google Chrome). While IE9 just fails without feedback, Firefox will gently advice that it cannot play that demo.